# Putting line from a file into file name

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, filenames

I have a `hdsentinel` executable script, and when I type

```
./hdsentinel
```

On the terminal I get info about my HDD health.

When I type:

```
./hdsentinel >hd.log
```

I get all that info in the `hd.log` file.

On location `/home/user/Desktop` I have a file example. In name of the file above hd.log, I want to input the 3rd line from file example (3rd line is 192.168.1.1) and result to be `hd192.168.1.1.log`.
How to do this?

Comment: please share the output of `./hdsentinel`

Comment: Hard Disk Sentinel for LINUX console 0.17.8556 (c) 2016 info@hdsentinel.com
Start with -r [reportfile] to save data to report, -h for help

Examining hard disk configuration ...

HDD Device  0: /dev/sda
HDD Model ID : TOSHIBA MQ01ACF050
HDD Serial No: X6L8C1ACT
HDD Revision : AV0D2C
HDD Size     : 476940 MB
Interface    : S-ATA Gen3, 6 Gbps
Temperature  : 38 °C
Highest Temp.: 46 °C
Health       : 100 %
Performance  : 100 %

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Here I am using sed to print the nth ( 3rd ) line of a file example and use the result of the expression `$(sed '3q;d' <example-file-path>)` in the output file name

```
./hdsentinel > "hd$(sed '3q;d' /home/user/Desktop/example).log"
```

**Explanation:**

```
sed 'NUMq;d' file
```

Where NUM is the number of the line you want to print; so, for example, sed '3q;d' file to print the 3rd line of file.

`NUMq` will quit immediately when the line number is `NUM`.

`d` will delete the line instead of printing it.

So all lines, except the NUMth will be deleted because the q causes the rest of the script to be skipped when quitting.

Comment: `sed 's/man/girl/'`
you are most welcome :)

Comment: @Arushix ... hahaha.. best comment I have read so far...